# SSRS web service 401 when i include Authorization http header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

We use both SSRS 2008 R2 and 2012. When i access a report using url access (direct ssrs server hit) and add a "Authorization: Bearer xyzelkalklsjsdfalsjdf" http header, i get a 401 from somewhere in the request pipeline. I have a custom httpmodule registered at the top of the chain which does some OAuth related security checks. But when this header is included, the request never reaches the httpmodule. If i change the header slightly ex: "YAuthorization: ljlxzcvc..", then the request reaches the httpmodule and everything works. So obviously SSRS is looking for a particular header named "Authorization" and does something with it. Point to note: we have implemented a custom forms authentication module and we are doing some rich authorization using the extensible ssrs api.

Now my questions are:

1. What is happening here? Who is acting on my request before my HttpModule registered on top in ssrs\reporting service\web.config gets it?
2. How do i ensure my httpmodule executes before whatever component is terminating my request with a 401